# Where can I find exercises to practice SQL statements?

Tags: sql

Do you know where I can find some practice SQL problems where I can write select statements?

Comment: Look at my comments below the chosen answer. You might get better stuff there than the junk at sql.ru, w3 schools etc.

Comment: HackeRank has a good collection of questions : https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/sql/select

Comment: Check out my book [SQL Practice Problems](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1520807635), available on Amazon. I wrote it specifically because it's easy to find SQL keyword and syntax info, but difficult to find good real-world practice in writing select statements.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[SQL exercises](http://www.sql-ex.ru/) or you can create a test table with fake data and manipulate that. Personally, I learn better with hands-on activity, by playing with the `SELECT` statements myself *before* even practicing an online guide. However, not everyone is the same.

Here are a few other links to check out:

- [SQLCourse](http://sqlcourse.com/) - Interactive for beginners.
- [SQLCourse2](https://www.youth4work.com/onlinetalenttest/Test-SQL-Server) - It's awesome you can try and sharpen your skills.

Good luck.

Comment: In one word - yuck ! Only if you can get the databases used, then go for examples like these - https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+assignments+with+solutions Or based on the public AdventureWorks DB for MS-SQL server - http://cuttingedgecourse.com/CIS310/Assignments.htm

Comment: Or search google like this - sql assignment site:.edu

Comment: This website, for example has IMDB (movies) website data and questions - http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse444/06wi/hw/hw1.htm

data for questions is here - http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse444/06wi/hw/IMDB.zip

Comment: This is the most complex query in page 10 of the "advanced course" - SELECT customers.customerid, customers.firstname, customers.lastname,
items_ordered.order_date, items_ordered.item, items_ordered.price
FROM customers, items_ordered
WHERE customers.customerid = items_ordered.customerid; 

Glance these sqlCourse links, but don't expect to get any real knowledge out of them.

Answer (score 6):

Look the line of books by Celko, it has lots of examples and exercises.

Answer (score 3):

You can find some [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp) as well.

Comment: Although really, I would download SQL Server Express, download the AdventureWorks db, and get a beginning SQL book like "Beginning SQL"

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Exercises](http://www.sql-ex.ru/).
Free and interactive.

Comment: Already posted in accepted answer.